# HTML/CSS | Remove Border Right from nested list

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I searched all over StackOverflow but couldn't find an answer to this one.

How can I get `border-right` to affect only the main `<li>`s (ie: "Border here ->") but not the nested `<li>`s (ie: "No border ->")?

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div,
nav {
  display: block;
}
.main-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
}
.block {
  width: 840px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.main-header ul.nav {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
}
#nav {
  z-index: 200;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
}
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
.main-header .nav-outer {
  padding: 0;
  position: static;
}
.main-header nav > div > ul > li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-right: 1px solid #993030;
}
.main-header nav > div > ul > li > ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: beige;
}
.main-header .nav > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background: #000;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2.083333333333vw;
}
.nav-home {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a {
  background: url(Images/nav-sprite.png) no-repeat center 14px;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #333;
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
  <div class="container nav-outer">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="block">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="nav-home"><a href="/homepage.html">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Border here -></a>

            <ul>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
              <li>No border -></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Border here -></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Border here -></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Border here -></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Border here -></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

A newbie here! Don't beat me up to bad if the code isn't properly organised :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` character in css will make your selector only target immediate descendants.  You want to target immediate descendants of the `nav` class which are `li` elements.  I have edited your css below.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div,
nav {
  display: block;
}
.main-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
}
.block {
  width: 840px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
.main-header ul.nav {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
}
#nav {
  z-index: 200;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
.container {
  max-width: 940px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
}
.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
.main-header .nav-outer {
  padding: 0;
  position: static;
}
.main-header nav > div > ul > li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 45px;
}
.main-header .nav > li > a {
  border-right: 1px solid #993030;
}
.main-header nav > div > ul > li > ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
  background-color: beige;
}
.main-header .nav > li > ul > li {
  display: block;
}
.nav li:hover {
  background: #000;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 2.083333333333vw;
}
.nav-home {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(213, 213, 213);
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a {
  background: url(Images/nav-sprite.png) no-repeat center 14px;
  text-indent: 200%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #333;
}
ul.nav li.nav-home a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: still have the same problem! is it because the nested list is all inside the the first li?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the complete css.  It should work for you.  I removed the border-right that you had and instead put it in .main-header .nav > li

Comment: actually it doesn't :( I tried it out here and still get the pesky border: https://jsfiddle.net/TRugeroni/z5gedgft/